# ubuntu installed on usb is currupted and booting on GUI.. how to repair usb pendrive as there is no operating system on internal hard disk

Tags: usb, bios, usb-installation

i had windows 10 running and i created USB ubuntu bootable ISO and installed and found that the image is currupted on usb and now i erased hard disk and tried installing ubuntu then i found that the image of usb is currupted and went to GUI based recovery ubuntu on Pendrive.. Now what is the procedure to install on internal hard disk. is it possible to download the image from network on hard disk and make it bootable by taking usb out.. or what are the precautions do I need to take. how do I make internal hard disk to boot ISO image as usb is currupted. is it possible to make bios based installation i do have internet and is it possible to download image on to hard disk and make it bootable get me correct ISO so that its not currupted.

---

creating live USB is not possible as iam booting laptop on USB currupted. i dont have second pendrive or laptop to format the USb and reinstall or repair..

I tried download

Wsl is not possible as it's formatted while installation so now am without any operating system with just usb bootable currupted os on it.. I can't make any changes on USB cause if I do.. laptop has no operating system and so is usb.. laptop reboots and goes into errors and won't boot at all.. can't format usb cause if I do then I don't have operating system at all

Comment: Please describe with more details what works and what does not work in the operating system on the USB drive. Can you run a terminal window? Can you download files? Can you install program packages? Can you create and mount a file system on the internal drive? In that case, can you read and write there? - Please describe what made the USB drive corrupted? At least what you *think* happened.

Comment: The procedure is complicated, if the computer starts from the USB you could try:
Start gparted.
Create a new partition table on the hard drive.

Create the required partitions for /, /home, /swap, UEFI if necessary and a partition of about 5 gigs at the end of the disk.
Install Grub on the hard drive.
Download the Ubuntu iso to the partition at the end of the disk.
Edit Grub to boot from the iso
Boot from the iso and install with non-automatic guided partitioning using the previously created partitions and respecting the one containing the iso.
There are tutorials about it

Comment: 1. yes i can run terminal window 2. I cant download files it goes halfway and download stops. I cant download iso. i can download rar files but dont know to install as am in root.. 3. yes i can mount a file system on the internal drive. No i cant write there 4. Yes USb drive is currupted. I did downloaded bootrepair and https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gHFTxdb57T/  6. UEFI procedure needed.. how to edit grub to boot from ISO boot and install non automatic guided partitions and respecting the one containing the iso. .. please give me the link for tutorials

Comment: You can try with a mini iso, it is Ubuntu 18, but if it installs then update it.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD
To boot from an iso with Grub
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot --- wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

How to install with manual partitioning
https://cyanogenmods.org/how-manually-partition-a-disk-during-installation-of-linux/

Comment: Can you open gparted on USB flash drive? It looks like you deleted the ESP - efi system partition on sda as sda2 does not start at beginning of drive and you do not have a sda1. If you can use gparted, create an ESP, FAT32 with esp,boot flags in gparted & then from Boot-Repair in UEFI boot mode & advanced mode do a full reinstall of grub.

Comment: It was installing grub and then it hung and after some time it took me to initframfs unable to mount filesystem.squashfs I checked the folder it's empty.. I don't have access to Gui anymore I feel to throw this off so many issues